# Is it a good idea to put user-definable types into callback prototypes?

Tags: c, types

In order to improve type safety in some C library code, I got the idea to use user-definable types in callback functions. So instead of carrying a `void*` around, the code uses a `Usertype*`. The library does only declare the type, but not define it, and uses this type as an opaque pointer. Instead of the regular scheme, that a library defines all used types, the parts which are used in callback functions are forward declared, and left to be defined by the user.

```
/*library code*/

struct UserDataForFooCallback; /* opaque user datatype */

typedef void CallbackFn(int i, struct UserDataForFooCallback* user);

void foo(CallbackFn* callback, struct UserDataForFooCallback* user)
{
    callback(42, user);
}


/*application code*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

struct UserDataForFooCallback
{
    int a;
};

static void fooCallback(int i, struct UserDataForFooCallback* user)
{
    printf(user->a == i ? "ok\n" : "fail\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct UserDataForFooCallback cbd = {42};
    foo(fooCallback, &cbd);
    return 0;
}
```

Advantages:

- Type safe callbacks
- no `struct MyFoo* data=arg` pointer assignments in the callback code

Drawbacks:

- AFAIK there must not be more than one definition of a user defined datatype (or am I mixing this with the one definition rule of C++?), which makes them problematic if there are more than uses of the back-calling function (say `foo` in the example is used by different program parts)
- The need to define a new type for every callback/group of callbacks (maybe it's not so important, since the many callback functions does use one already)

The main thing I want to know if this is really a good idea, or if thie is only a good-looking-but-Armageddon-like-impact idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are two libraries using your library, that both defined `UserDataForFooCallback` as a different structure, it is One Definition Rule violation. Just stick with `void*`.

Comment: I second this. Stick with `void *`. Virtually every C libraries providing a callback mechanism uses pointers to void to pass around extra data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about type of the user data, you can always use void*. Then people can send whatever data they want.

Note that it's a C-way of implementing that. If you're using C++, you can create a base class and derive from it. Of course, your callback's argument should be the base class.